# How can I pass a dictionary argument to *args without unpacking it?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I have sort of an opposite problem to some of the questions I've come across: How can I pass a dictionary as an argument **without** unpacking it? I've recently updated Python and SciPy to 3.7.6 and 1.5.0, respectively, and this behavior appears to have changed since my previous several-years-old environment.

The specific case I'm trying to address is for `scipy.optimize.newton`, where my function takes one additional argument, a dictionary of string:float pairs. For example,

```
def myfunc(x,p):
    y = p["a"]*x + p["b"]
    return y

mydict = {"a":1,"b":2}
x0 = 0
newton(myfunc,x0,args=(mydict))
```

returns a `TypeError`:
`myfunc() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

It seems that in `scipy\optimize\zeros.py`, line 326,
`q0 = func(p0, *args)` unpacks the dictionary. How can I get around this?

Comment: `args=(mydict)` -> `args=(mydict,)`. Note the trailing comma. What you have a is a no-op, you need the comma to create a tuple in Python.

Comment: I see - thank you!